# Intel i9 7980XE Are these parts compatible?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, hard-disk, power-supply

I am looking to go big on cores and have bought the Intel i9 7980XE 18 core processor. I'm trying to find a sane list of parts that will be compatible - I haven't built a computer for about 10 years and things have changed!

These guys have a list for the 7960X but I'm wondering if the parts are good enough to deal with the 7980XE?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0VtuTiwi-k

ASUS Prime X299-Deluxe Mother Board

Corsair Dominator Platinum 64GB (8 x 8GB)

Seasonic Prime Titanium 1000 SSR-1000TD

Samsung SSD 850 Pro 2TB

Samsung SSD 850 EVO 2TB

Samsung NVMe SSD 960 Pro M.2 1TB

Samsung NVMe 960 Pro M.2 512GB

Fractal Design Define R5 w/o window white case

Fractal Design CPU Water Cooler Celsius S36

Fractal Fans

GTX1080ti

Hard Drives WD 6TB Green

So I have a few questions:

One thing i'm wondering is about the storage. They seem to be recommending 5 hard drives. I've never heard of these nvme m.2 drives before but presumably if I only need a small amount of storage then the 512GB m.2 one will be enough for everything, no need for the 1TB m.2 or the other SSDs right?

Will the 650 Watt version of the power supply (https://www.amazon.co.uk/Seasonic-Prime-Titanium-Modular-Supply/dp/B01HXYRJYK) be enough to fuel everything?

I don't need a mega graphics card. This isn't going to be a gaming machine and all I need is to connect an HDMI screen. Can you give me a reason to not get a really cheap graphics card like this? https://www.ebuyer.com/806221-asus-geforce-gt-710-graphics-card-gt710-sl-1gd5

Comment: Unfortunatly, build requests/reviews are off-topic for this site. Please see my [question series](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A60+is%3Aquestion+college) for an example of how to ask these types of questions. Also, I would not recommend buying/building a computer without understanding your use case. All I see is that you want many cores and this will not be a gaming system. If you do decide to break up this question, please list the goals of this system and how you till be using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knocking through the questions:

1. Storage is really up to you.   M2 drives are just a really fast connection that enjoys about 4x the write speed of SATA.  This means, from the perspective of a user, near instantaneous reads and writes.  Beyond that, it's basically the same technology as a normal SSD, so you're talking quarter seconds versus full seconds.  If you're making your storage decisions based on speed, SSD and M2 are the way to go. Same for longevity, as they last a couple of years longer than a classic mechanical HDD.  If you're basing it on capacity alone, you would obviously want HDD, but you may prefer a BD-RW that can write to [M-Disc](http://www.mdisc.com/mdisc-technology/) and a few of those discs for your long-term, read-only media like pictures of the family. The expense is higher but you'd get better storage than any of the other solutions for longevity.
2. With all of that hardware, a 650w PSU will be cutting it close, especially with a 1080ti in there (we will get to that in a second).  The PSU is one of the most important purchases in a PC or server build of any kind.  I'd look in the 850w+ range from a company with a good reputation and support like Antec or EVGA. The CPU may be an extremely important part of a computer purchase, but without the PSU, the CPU is just a block of expensive and cold silicon.  With a bad one, your whole build can die in a literal fire.  Never skimp on the PSU.
3. If you don't plan to game and aren't buying four of them to mine bitcoin and make gamers hate you for inflating the price even further, you don't need the 1080ti.  Not only is this WAY overpowered if you are just using the machine for a server and HTPC, but it's also not financially wise right now.  Video card prices are horribly inflated due to the fact GPUs are what you use to mine cryptocurrency, and it's killing the supply while the craze continues. I wouldn't bother with the GT-710, though.  It's an older card.  Honestly, if the most you plan to do is watch a movie as far as graphics are concerned, I would just get a 1050 or 950.  That motherboard doesn't appear to have HDMI out; if it did, I'm pretty sure you wouldn't need a video card, as I think the i9 still has the on-die video capability that the other series processors have.

Just as a personal note, if you're not primarily running this as a server, that i9 won't get put to use.   Modern processors for personal use typically cap out at the next step down.  The i9 and the AMD Threadripper are specifically intended for massive amounts of multitasking and multithreaded activities such as video encoding (as in, from scratch in a video editing environment) or server-grade shared processing.  If you're not using this for a professional purpose like that, you will save money and even get increased performance out of an i7 or an i5 in comparison.  Please note in [this benchmark](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i9-7980XE-vs-Intel-Core-i7-8700K/m352013vs3937) that a new-generation i7 that costs 1/6th the price outperforms the i9 you have selected in applications that use less than 5 cores; that's 90% of the consumer software market.  File server use won't change much between processors; that's not a CPU intensive activity.  If you plan to host applications for your whole household or business to be clients to this as a server, however, the i9 would be more worth it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went with the 650Watt in the end but also the low end graphics card so I hope it'll be ok!

Comment: Sounds good, the low-end GPU shouldn't have much TDP so you are probably fine that way.  If not, I see the EVGA 850w Bronze (which isn't their best, but is still really good) go on sale often.  Don't forget to click the checkmark next to the answer if I answered your questions!